# How the functions arguments are being removed

Tags: assembly, x86, 32-bit, callstack, calling-convention

While I was looking over some assembly code I noticed that a function has the following structure:

```
My_Function:
  ; Function Prologue
  push EBP
  mov EBP, ESP
  sub ESP, 0x28 ;40 Bytes local variable allocation

  ; Some code here

  ; Function epilogue
  leave
  ret
```

So if we suppose that the `My_Function` takes an argument of 1 byte, so where is removed from stack frame. As far as I know that a function's stack contains the following structure (from lower to higher addresses):

```
LOW ADDRESS >  | Local Variables |
               |  Old EBP Value  |
               |  Return Address |
HIGH ADDRESS > |    Arguments    |
               -------------------
               | Previous Stack  |
               |     Frame       |
```

Which assembly command "removes" the function's arguments?

As far as I know `leave` and `ret` (so called function epilogue) modify `$esp` and `$ebp` registers in values in order to point into previous stack frame. But I am not sure whether `$esp` when function epilogue gets executed will point exactly when the local variables from previous stack frame "start" as you can see:

Before executing function epilogue:

```
LOW ADDRESS >  | Local Variables | < ESP
               |  Old EBP Value  | < EBP
               |  Return Address |
               |    Arguments    |
               -------------------
               | Local Variables |
               |  Old EBP Value  |
               |  Return Address |
HIGH ADDRESS > |    Arguments    |
```

After executing function epilogue there are 2 options:

1) Option 1:

```
LOW ADDRESS >  | Local Variables | < ESP
               |  Old EBP Value  | < EBP
               |  Return Address |
```

HIGH ADDRESS >  |    Arguments    |

2) Option 2:

```
               |    Arguments    | < ESP
               -------------------
LOW ADDRESS >  | Local Variables | 
               |  Old EBP Value  | < EBP
               |  Return Address |
```

HIGH ADDRESS >  |    Arguments    |

Which one of theese options are the correct one and which command of the function is responsible for making the `esp` register pointing to the correct address?

Comment: The example is not complete as you either `enter` together with `leave` or at least `leave` must have an additional argument...

Comment: Neither of those. This looks like cdecl convention where the caller removes the arguments.

Comment: @UwePlonus the code is fine. `leave` doesn't take an argument and you don't have to use `enter`.

Comment: @UwePlonus: `enter` is very slow; it's much faster to use `push ebp` / `mov ebp, esp` / `sub esp, 0x28` instead of `enter 0, 0x28`, so that's what compilers do.  But `leave` is only 3 uops on mainstream Intel CPUs (http://agner.org/optimize/), about the same as `mov esp, ebp` / `pop ebp`, so compilers do use it.

Comment: the code you posted does NOT remove anything from stack, it will return to the caller as it was. The code does modify only its own stack space, under arguments. Anyway, if you dare to figure out how more complex code works, just fire it up in debugger, and watch `esp` plus the memory area there.

Comment: I updated the example

Answer (score -3):

It is not always that a function's arguments are passed on the stack. Most ABI conventions for x86 and x86-64 dictate to pass first arguments in registers, and only when there are too many of them pass the rest on stack.

An except from x86-64 ABI: https://www.uclibc.org/docs/psABI-x86_64.pdf on calling conventions:

[image: calling conventions]

The advantage of that is that memory accesses are slower than register accesses, so whenever possible they have to be avoided. The same happens with the return value - if possible it is returned on a register.

If there indeed are arguments on the stack, as well as local automatic variables, they can be "deallocated" simply by restoring previously saved RSP value. Doesn't `leave` do exactly that?

Comment: `leave` doesn't pop stack args, only locals.  `ret 8` would pop 8 bytes of args, but the OP isn't using that, so it's a caller-pops convention (like i386 and x86-64 System V) where any stack offset created by the caller is still there when the function returns.  It's up to the caller how to do that.  But yes, if the caller of this function also made a stack frame and used `leave`, that would be one way to do it.

Comment: And BTW, *most* 32-bit calling conventions are old and bad, and use stack-args exclusively.  Including for example i386 System V, and this question is tagged 32-bit.  Yes that's a useful point to make, but x86-64 System V still does use stack args for aggregates too large for a couple registers, or after running out of registers.  Anyway, there can always be stack args, so "there usually aren't any" doesn't work as the main part of an answer to how they're dealt with, especially not for 32-bit where it isn't true.